# Upgrading Debian stable daily

Tags: debian, ubuntu, cron, upgrade, repository

I've installed Debian stable 9.3 server for an Nginx environment, and I consider upgrading it daily via cron:

```
0 0 * * * apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
```

My system is minimal and uncustomized: It's a VPS to run a webserver with only these ports open: 22, 80, 443, 9000.

My system has no third-party software (that is, software originating outside the Debian repositoirs), besides `CSF-LFD`, `Maldet` and `WP-CLI`.

---

Is it still problematic to upgrade daily as I plan to do? Given I host at DigitalOcean I've asked the DigitalOcean support about this and they said it should be okay but added something like *"there has been some webservers that stopped working due to such upgrades"* (it isn't clear if the aforementioned webservers and their environments where of a similar, let alone identical, stack and if they even were Debian stable).

Do you also see a problem in the daily upgrade approach I take to my specific minimalist stack?

I assume I don't want to use `unattended-upgrades` that gives only security upgrades. I want to make sure everything is upgraded. This was my main reason to move from Ubuntu 16.04 xenial to Debian stable.

I guess this answer can indeed have an answer like "generally it is a wrong approach considering your current stack" or "generally it isn't wrong considering your current stack".

Comment: You can configure `unattended-upgrades` to apply all updates, not just security updates...

Comment: Is it different, significantly the cron command I listed above?

Comment: Yes, it includes a whole lot of checks and edge cases for when a blanket "Just toss it in and don't worry about consequences" might not be wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your premise is flawed — `unattended-upgrades` can be configured to apply any update, not just security updates. It also takes care of quite a bit more than just `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`: it will avoid starting upgrades which require interaction (*e.g.* for configuration changes), it can be given a list of packages *not* to upgrade, it can handle incomplete `dpkg` runs, it can send email in a variety of circumstances (`cron` will do that too), it can reboot automatically if necessary (which is useful following a kernel upgrade), etc.

See [its documentation](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md) for details.